# "overflow-x: auto' not working on table in CSS Grid to make it scrollable for responsiveness, how do I fix?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am creating a Wordpress theme and am trying to redesign tables that are already within the content of the site that I'll be installing the theme on. All of my changes to the table have worked except for adding an 'overflow-x: auto' to its container div to make the table horizontally scrollable when on mobile. Currently the table resizes its width based on the size of the viewport but when it can't get any smaller it maintains its size and makes the entire page scrollable.

I have looked at a lot of other questions and answers on stackoverflow that are similar to this but they seem not to be working for me. I have created a div container around the table and added 'overflow-x: auto' to it but it doesn't do anything.

EDIT: This seems to be working fine in the the StackOverflow code snippet but not in my Wordpress site. Is this a problem with Wordpress?

EDIT 2: When I installed a table plugin it still had the same issue. When contacting the creator of the plugin they said the issue is that I'm using CSS Grid's 'grid-column' and that the table parent is not responsive. I didn't think this was an issue before so I did not include it in my code here. I have edited the code below to reflect what I am using in CSS Grid and so the StackOverflow code snippet now reflects how it's not working.

```css
.table-template {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 10px 1fr 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 100px 0;
}

.table-area {
    grid-column: 2 / 3;
}


.table-overflow {
   
    overflow-x: auto;
    
    }

    table {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
   
    }

    thead {
    background-color: #efc879;
    font-weight: bold;
    }

    td, tr, th {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    th, td {
   
    }
    th {
    font-weight: bold;
    }
    tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #ececec;
    }

    td {
    padding: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<main class="table-template">
   
   <section class="table-area">
      <div class="table-overflow">
      <table>
        <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td></td>
           <td>SF</td>
           <td>CS</td>
           <td>NM</td>
           <td>JC</td>
           <td>JH</td>
           <td>MT</td>
           <td>KF</td>
           <td>TG</td>
           <td>TOTAL</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Person</td>
           <td style="background-position: 0% 50%; background-color: black;">XXX</td>
           <td align="center">0</td>
           <td align="center">0</td>
           <td align="center">0(d)</td>
           <td align="center">0(d)</td>
           <td align="center">0(d)</td>
           <td align="center">0(d)</td>
           <td align="center">1</td>
           <td align="center">1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>Person</td>
           <td align="center">1</td>
           <td style="background-position: 0% 50%; background-color: black;">XXX</td>
           <td align="center">1</td>
           <td align="center">1</td>
           <td align="center">1</td>
           <td align="center">0</td>
           <td align="center">0</td>
           <td align="center">1</td>
           <td align="center">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Person</td>
          <td align="center">1</td>
          <td align="center">0</td>
          <td style="background-position: 0% 50%; background-color: black;">XXX</td>
          <td align="center">0(d)</td>
          <td align="center">0</td>
          <td align="center">0</td>
          <td align="center">1</td>
          <td align="center">1</td>
          <td align="center">3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Person</td>
          <td align="center">0.5(a)</td>
          <td align="center">0</td>
          <td align="center">0(d)</td>
          <td style="background-position: 0% 50%; background-color: black;">XXX</td>
          <td align="center">0</td>
          <td align="center">1</td>
          <td align="center">0</td>
          <td align="center">0</td>
          <td align="center">1.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Person</td>
          <td align="center">0.5(a)</td>
          <td align="center">0</td>
          <td align="center">1</td>
          <td align="center">1</td>
          <td style="background-position: 0% 50%; background-color: black;">XXX</td>
          <td align="center">1</td>
          <td align="center">1</td>
          <td align="center">1</td>
          <td align="center">5.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Person</td>
          <td align="center">0.5(a)</td>
          <td align="center">1</td>
          <td align="center">1</td>
          <td align="center">0</td>
          <td align="center">0</td>
          <td style="background-position: 0% 50%; background-color: black;">XXX</td>
          <td align="center">0</td>
          <td align="center">0</td>
          <td align="center">2.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Person</td>
          <td align="center">0.5(a)</td>
          <td align="center">1</td>
          <td align="center">0</td>
          <td align="center">1</td>
          <td align="center">0</td>
          <td align="center">1</td>
          <td style="background-position: 0% 50%; background-color: black;">XXX</td>
          <td align="center">0</td>
          <td align="center">3.5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Person</td>
          <td align="center">0</td>
          <td align="center">0</td>
          <td align="center">0</td>
          <td align="center">1</td>
          <td align="center">0</td>
          <td align="center">1</td>
          <td align="center">1</td>
          <td style="background-position: 0% 50%; background-color: black;">XXX</td>
          <td align="center">3</td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </section>
 </main>
```

Currently the table resizes its width based on the size of the viewport but when it can't get any smaller it maintains its size and makes the entire page scrollable.

Comment: Add `width:100%` in .table-overflow class.

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Could be a caching problem. To see if i have the same issue, What is the site you're working on ?

Comment: Well I am creating a new theme in my local environment where I am performing this so the old site theme shouldn't matter should it? The site I am working on is http://www.irish-go.org/

Comment: Well in that case checking the website doesn't help, try adding a min-width to the table at the respective break points

Comment: Ok, I've gotten it to work by setting the table to 'display: block' and added a fixed px width to the <table>. I'll just have to adjust it via media queries. Not perfect but only solution that's working for now.

Comment: If you're working with table never touch the display property of it's elements that's the whole point of having a table layout

Comment: Then can you recommend another way for me to achieve my goal? I'm not able to add a container to the Wordpress Gutenberg 'wp:table'. My only option has been to change the display of the table element which is working fine right now. Adding min-width to the table doesn't work for me.

Comment: Ok so I've been alerted to the fact that it is a problem with my CSS Grid code. Can you look at my 'EDIT 2' above and advise?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            margin: 0px;
        }
        table {
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
            border-spacing: 0;
        }
        thead {
            background-color: #efc879;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        td,
        tr,
        th {
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
        th,
        td {
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }
        th {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #ececec;
        }
        td {
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>SF</td>
                        <td>CS</td>
                        <td>NM</td>
                        <td>JC</td>
                        <td>JH</td>
                        <td>MT</td>
                        <td>KF</td>
                        <td>TG</td>
                        <td>TOTAL</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Person</td>
                        <td style="background-position: 0% 50%; background-color: black;">XXX</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td align="center">0(d)</td>
                        <td align="center">0(d)</td>
                        <td align="center">0(d)</td>
                        <td align="center">0(d)</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Person</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td style="background-position: 0% 50%; background-color: black;">XXX</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td align="center">5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Person</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td style="background-position: 0% 50%; background-color: black;">XXX</td>
                        <td align="center">0(d)</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td align="center">3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Person</td>
                        <td align="center">0.5(a)</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td align="center">0(d)</td>
                        <td style="background-position: 0% 50%; background-color: black;">XXX</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td align="center">1.5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Person</td>
                        <td align="center">0.5(a)</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td style="background-position: 0% 50%; background-color: black;">XXX</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td align="center">5.5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Person</td>
                        <td align="center">0.5(a)</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td style="background-position: 0% 50%; background-color: black;">XXX</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td align="center">2.5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Person</td>
                        <td align="center">0.5(a)</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td style="background-position: 0% 50%; background-color: black;">XXX</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td align="center">3.5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Person</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td align="center">0</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td align="center">1</td>
                        <td style="background-position: 0% 50%; background-color: black;">XXX</td>
                        <td align="center">3</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but the issue is down to the use of a flexible unit Fr in `grid-template-columns: 10px 1fr 10px;`.

You need to use an absolute value, for example, `grid-template-columns: 10px calc(100% - 20px) 10px;`